# How to skip an annotation call based on a flag in the same class

Tags: java, spring, annotations, spring-annotations

I have couple of annotations on a getter as below. I would like to skip all the annotations call on the getter based on a boolean in the same class. Is there any way to do it?

```
@MyAnnotation1(message = "{someMessage1}")
@MyAnnotation2(message = "{someMessage2}")
public Date getFromDate() {
    return fromDate;
}
```

Comment: annotations are read by other programs to get metadata. what prog do you want to ignore it?

Comment: If this is an spring annotation, please specify the exact annotations you are using. There no general solution that works for all kinds of annotations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define another annotation as `@Ignore` on that field if that annotated field is set you can simply ignore your annotation processing.

```
   @Ignore
   private boolean value;
```

You can define your own annotation as

```
   @Target(ElementType.FIELD)
   @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
   /**
    * This Annotation should be used on boolean field to set specify whether annotation processing should be        ignored for that class
    */
   public @interface Ignore {

   }
```

**Remember this is custom annotation so you will need to write code to handle it**

PS Note: Assuming you are writing custom annotations. And there processing.

Comment: what class is `@Ignore` defined in?